# Attributes of CommandEvent

Tags: wxpython

What are the `get()` attributes of command event in wxPython just like `getid()`?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxcommandevent.html#wxcommandevent

```
wxCommandEvent::GetClientData
wxCommandEvent::GetClientObject
wxCommandEvent::GetExtraLong
wxCommandEvent::GetInt
wxCommandEvent::GetSelection
wxCommandEvent::GetString
```

And those inherited from its superclass:

```
wxEvent::GetEventObject
wxEvent::GetEventType
wxEvent::GetId
wxEvent::GetSkipped
wxEvent::GetTimestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have documentation available justuse python to print all Get methods

```
>>> print [c for c in dir(wx.CommandEvent) if c.startswith('Get') ]
```

it prints 
['GetClassName', 'GetClientData', 'GetClientObject', 'GetEventObject',
 'GetEventType', 'GetExtraLong', 'GetId', 'GetInt', 'GetSelection', 'GetSkipped', 'GetString', 'GetTimestamp']